# How to send video with SMTP in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, email, smtp

I'm using SMTP framework to send an email with an video. The code for send images and text is:

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,

                           @"Some text to include in body",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture1"];
NSData *vcfData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 50);
NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image/jpg;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"image.jpg\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                         @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"image.jpg\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[vcfData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

And then add the part(image) to NSArray parts to send this.

```
 testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];
```

But I don't know how can I add a video. For an image is UIImage, but for video?

How can I add a Video to this?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, sending such huge files as videos by e-mail is a bad idea. Transmission will take forever, there will be message size limits on some servers, and you will be likely to be caught by spam filters. I'd recommend sending only a link to a download, maybe protected with a password or something.

Comment: I want send a little video, and I know that this form isn't recommended but I need use SMTP..

Comment: With this code I get error, return nil while send message... NSDictionary *vcfPart3 =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"video/mov;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                             @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[data encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];        What could be the problem? Thanks!